# Text align not working for specific length div

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui

I have a kendo UI multi selct with a custom tag template. The following is happening, in particular with user Gary Austin. Because the job title is longer than the number and the Name it is causing UI issues.

[image: Screenshot]

Proper Kendo UI Dojo example can be found here: https://dojo.telerik.com/ItECorEK

How do I ensure that each tag is set correctly like so:
[image: Correct Output]

Comment: It's hard to tell whats happening without be able to inspect the whole DOM context. It seems that `div.multi-select-counter` is getting larger (even having `width: 20px`) and pushing `div.keyContactName` to the right. But I can't be sure. Can you post a working demo in dojo.telerik.com with your scenario?

Comment: I forgot about Kendo dojo, find the example here: https://dojo.telerik.com/ItECorEK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this css statement:

```
.k-multiselect li {
    text-align: left
}
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ItECorEK/2)

Comment: Well that was easy! Thanks :)